# How to have console window with debugger window

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm debugging bugs on IE.

How do I have the console window inside debugger window?

So that I could inspect variables and make some expressions on the fly without switching back and forth.

Any idea? Like what we did on Chrome.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have a console window with in debugger window in Internet Explorer browser.

First, you need to open debugger window in developer tools.

Than you will see a Show console button on the right side of document mode button on the menu bar of the developer tools.

[image]

You can click that button to display console in debugger.

[image]

Comment: you're awesome!